# Good books for Hadoop, Spark, and Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-hadoop

Can anyone suggest any good books to learn hadoop and map reduce basics?

Also something for Spark, and Spark Streaming?

Thanks

Comment: This type of question is considered off topic for StackExchange.

Comment: Is it? That's quite interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's such an overwhelming amount of literature that with programming, databases, and Big Data I like to stick to the O'reilly series as my go-to source. O'reilly books are extremely popular in the industry and I've been very satisfied.

A current version of

1. [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do),
2. [MapReduce Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do), and
3. [Learning Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do)

might suit your needs by providing high quality, immediately useful information and avoiding information overload -- all are published by O'reilly.

Spark Streaming is covered in Chapter 13 of "Learning Spark".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good [open source book for spark](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

for hadoop try [hadoop in action](http://www.amazon.in/Hadoop-Action-Chuck-Lam/dp/8177228137?tag=googinhydr18418-21)  or [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://www.amazon.in/Hadoop-The-Definitive-Guide-White/dp/9350237563?tag=googinhydr18418-21)